# set_cookie слетают

Tags: php, битрикс

Значение в переменной `$APPLICATION->set_cookie` слетает при обновлении страницы. В чем проблема? С браузером всё нормально.

Comment: Такая короткая формулировка вопроса не оставляет зацепок.
Как именно и где вы ставите куку? Покажите код.
Как и где получаете? Покажите код.
Вопрос может быть во времени, пути или домене, но точно понять без кода невозможно.

Comment: Да и вообще, set_cookie метод, который устанавливает куки, а не переменная. Правильно вам говорят, покажите код.